# RSpec-Rails - stub a controller variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, instance-variables, stub

I have a controller action I want to test:

```
LOG = ApiRequest::Resource::Login

def create
    @response = LOG.new(current_user, params: params).create
    return if request_failed?
    ...
end

def request_failed?
    if @response.is_a? Hash
      false
    else
      error = @response
      redirect_to new_login_path, alert: error
      true
    end
  end
```

`LOG.new(current_user, params: params).create` is an external api call that normally returns either a hash or a string with the error. I want to test the controller action without triggering the call, like force `@response = {}` and check if it doesn't redirect and force `@response = ""` which should trigger a redirect.

```
it 'redirects if fails the request' do
    post :create
    expect(response).to redirect_to new_login_path
    expect(flash[:alert]).not_to be nil
end
```

How can you stub an instance variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would test it with stubbing `LOG` instance, something like:

```
let(:log_instance) { instance_double(LOG) }

before do
  allow(LOG).to receive(:new).and_return(log_instance)
  allow(log_instance).to receive(:create).and_return({})
end
```

Comment: You have to use ControllerName::LOG to access the constant, other than that it worked!